# Pandoc HTML to PDF with Styling

Tags: pandoc

I have an HTML document that I would like to convert to a PDF using `pandoc` and `wkhtmltopdf` as the engine.

Based on the [pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf), I am running the following command:

`pandoc index.html -t html -o test.pdf --css=style.css`

When I do so, I get the following output:

`Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: Failed to load file:///var/folders/6d/rt2z_w650f1_xfkq8g7sm59m0000gn/T/style.css (ignore)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done`

If I list the documents in the directory in which I ran that command, I get the following:

`index.html
style.css`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There was [a bug](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4413) in pandoc 2.1.3 (and possibly earlier versions).

Try upgrading to [the most recent release](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases).

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years old, nevertheless (in case someone is looking this up) I'll point out a typo (in Steve's question or how he actually ran it, I don't know). He had:

`pandoc index.html -t html -o test.pdf --css=style.css`

`-t html` means "**to** HTML" ... this needs `-f html -t pdf`, as in:

`pandoc index.html -f html -t pdf -o test.pdf --css=style.css`

Have a terrific day!